# How to know about errors when using Table class store method without using getError

Tags: database, jtable

I'm wondering how to find errors when a table class is used, inheriting from \Joomla\CMS\Table and using the store method?

It appears that in Table, the store method traps errors in a try-catch structure. It seems to use its own deprecated setError method and returns false.

In the calling code, how is it possible to find out what error has occurred without using the deprecated getError method?

Comment: You could override the store() method used by placing your own store() in a higher class and then use a more modern approach to catch the exception

Comment: Thanks, yes, I could certainly do that. Or I could use a different class altogether, I have suitable code. But maybe the basic question is where is Joomla going? Is the Table class obsolete? It relies on a deprecated method and appears to have no usable error handling. What are developers supposed to do?